# A PHP Dice Roller with Database Read/Write

Tags: php, mysql, dice

I fear I'm biting off a project that is far more advanced that I realize, but I would like to make a small PHP app, and simply don't know where to begin.

The app needs to:

- roll an entire set of D&D dice
- impose the results of each roll atop the image of it's corresponding die
- generate a random validation ID
- write the roll results, the validation ID, as well as the date and time of the roll to a MySQL database
- Allow the user to save (For posting for forums) the image of the rolled dice, displaying the validation ID.
- Allow other users (the DM, specifically) to enter a validation code and verify the rolls, time, and date - to prevent dishonesty.

Optional things that would be GREAT, but I fear would make this project even more involved:

- A re-roll preventor of some sort (a time delay per IP between rolls, or maybe user sessions in which a DM can set the order in which players must roll (the DM could, of course, roll for absent players)).

So that's the goal, now on to the question: I am, essentially, a newb. I can edit PHP code, and write simplistic code if I have a cheatsheet handy. But what I want to ask of the good StackOverflow folks is:

- Is this a challenge I should attempt to take on with my limited knowledge? If so, where should I turn for education that might help me along this path - if not, what is my most cost-effective method of finding someone who could create this code for me (I'm not looking for anything exclusive, once the code is created, I'll be posting it online for free and public use)?

Comment: This question is [outside the scope of StackOverflow itself](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). Perhaps it would be better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com, although I 'm far from sure. Even so, considering that this is a new user we should perhaps refrain from downvoting and focus on indoctrinating.

Comment: You won't know until you try.  Why not give it a shot?

Comment: i agree with both comments - it is off topic, but you should try it - it's a great way to learn.

Comment: Most of the functionality seems rather basic (As in, it's doable without deep knowledge of php), the image part might be tricky for someone who's never had experience with it. I'd say give it a go

Comment: it's a fun project that can evolve in steps - start with a simple roller that can throw some dice on page refresh, then make it customizable via a form or GET params, etc.

Comment: The good thing with your project, is that you seem to have a fine understanding of your goals, divided in clear steps. The project may cause intimidation as a whole, but if you challenge it step by step, you will eventually get to finish it successfully, having learnt a lot in the process.

Comment: What is keeping the user from re-rolling and presenting the next result instead? Do you plan to have a unique ID (maybe sequential) that is provided by the counterparty receiving the die roll?

Comment: as others have said start with the basics so start with roll generation, then work out how to assign that roll a unique id and add it to the database (hint auto increment primary key in db will do) then work out how to allow people to retrieve rolls based off the input of the primary key and do the image generation absolubtly last as that will probably be your most difficult part.  the rest of it you could probably find the code you need to copy and paste if you searched correctly

Comment: Could you define "roll an entire set of D&D dice"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly simple. The php aspect uses mostly http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php functions. The rest is done with HTML/CSS. So you will need those skills as well.

To make a roll ID add a auto increment ID column in mysql and store the dice rolls there.

Comment: These are great links - and I know I'll learn a lot reading over them. Do you have any suggestions regarding the generation of an image from the results (as opposed to having the user take a manual screen cap)?

Comment: GD or imagemagik for image creation. both will do what you want to do in about 5 lines just instead of echo out your result to the screen as normal you use them as inputs at x,y coords to position them in the correct location on your blank dice picture. then save/write the image to a folder and store the file name in the database. that way you can call back the image remotely at any time or download and email it etc whatever you want.

Comment: @user2370304 you should not generate an image. Instead have an image of the dice you have drawn or got from a free source, and use HTML text and CSS to overlay the text of the dice roll on that image. Users can take a screenshot with the dice and the verification ID. Or they could just paste the numbers with the verification ID. If you must generate images, look at PHP GD library which is easy to generate images.